# Login Tenant after registration in central database package used stancl/tenancy laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, multi-tenant

I am using **stancl/tenancy** to implement multiple database multitenancy in my laravel app. The tenants can register through the central domain (example.com) and all things works fine but i want to login the tenant after redirect to his subdomain (tenant.example.com).
I tried to authenticate the tenant after registration process but it doesn't work.
My register controller code like:

[image: My code]

I tried to authenticate the tenant after registration process but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tenant->run(function () {
    User::create(...);
});
```

I'll come up with a more constructive answer later, for the main time you can leverage on the above code.

Reference: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/tenants#running-commands-in-the-tenant-context